# How to execute the output of a command inside a scriptblock tag?

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

***THIS IS JUST A PROOF OF CONCEPT***

I have the following code I wrote that will store the description of a module in a variable and then execute it:

`$p = Find-Module tpl | select -ExpandProperty 'Description';& ([scriptblock]::Create($p))`

the description is an echo command:
`echo "this is a proof of concept"`

I have shortened it a little using aliases:

`$p = Fimo tpl | select -Exp 'Des*';& ([scriptblock]::Create($p))`

I believe it can be shortened even further using something like:

`Icm -ScriptBlock {Fimo tpl|select -Exp 'Des*'}`

but this just returns the whole output:
`echo "this is a proof of concept"`

instead of executing it.

How can I get it to execute the command inside the scriptblock tag?

Comment: `& ([scriptblock]::Create((Fimo tpl).Description))` ?

Comment: you will forever be a legend Santiago. just got a job as a junior pentester and have been experimenting with some weird concepts

Comment: `iex (Fimo tpl).Description` is shorter. and you're playing with fire here

Comment: im def aware. why im trying to bring this concept up

Comment: Leaving the code-golf aspect aside, all these commands should (mostly) exhibit the same behavior (the `iex` command runs directly in the caller's scope, not in a child scope the way the `& ...` commands do). If your `.Description` property truly contains a string with _verbatim_ value `echo "this is a proof of concept"`, all of these commands should work as intended - none would output `echo "this is a proof of concept"`, all would output verbatim `this is a proof of concept`

Comment: I think your question has been answered and has been answered before (see linked question) so I think it's safe to close it as a duplicate unless there is something we're missing